# Canvas easing glitches

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to do this dynamic menu in canvas where the menu bar will follow the mouse and stop moving when mouse is over it. My problem is when the bar moves it start jumping around (glitches), but when I make it stop on mouse over it start glitching like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/577vh5dc/

```js
    if (!(position.x <= x + 100 && position.x >= x - 85 ) || !(position.y <= y + 400 && position.y >= y - 70)) {
      x += EasingFunctions.easeInOutQuad(t) * (position.x - x);
      y += EasingFunctions.easeInOutQuad(t) * (position.y - y);
    }
```

Can anyone help me making it move smoothly and stop on mouse over?

Regards.

Comment: look at your post, and notice things didn't format like you thought it would. You'll need to fix that before people can answer you.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that... I have it sorted out

Comment: can you reduce the code to only have the bits that cause the problematic behaviour? There's a lot of functions here that aren't involved in the problem you're asking about.

Comment: A commenting off of `if (!(position.x <= x + 100 && position.x >= x - 85 ) || !(position.y <= y + 400 && position.y >= y - 70)) {` and its corresponding `}` fixes the problem entirely (a thing you should generally give a try first, as part of preparing the minimal working example for your question)

Comment: Yes it works fine when I take off the if statement but I need the that condition in order to make it stop while mouse is over the menu area so you can click in others buttons (those squares are meant to be buttons). I believe it's something with maths when mouse is in certain areas it's  probably giving unexpected position.

Comment: By the way thanks for replying :)

Comment: yeah, so we can determine that the if statement is causing coordinate rewrite issues (such as some form of `if x<a, x=a+1`), and should probably be rewritten with some more care, so it's worth running through on paper (or console.log for all values) for two or three iterations, to see what it's exactly doing when things start to jump around.